# Copy-pasting between two computers , or a virtual machine and host?

Tags: virtual-machine, macros, copy-paste

In my work, I find myself hopping between a VPN machine and my host machine to do work.

Lately I've been using https://www.cl1p.net/ a lot , for copy-pasting between 2 computers.

A nice site, wonderful idea. But it's only somewhat reliable, unfortunately..

What are faster and more effective ways to copy-paste between 2 computers?

I need to know how to do this, or perhaps how to reliably use cl1p. I found that cl1p.net works better if I use strange URLs rather than common words. But if anyone knows the scoop, much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/copy-paste-virtualbox-host-guest-machines/

Comment: @Adel How exactly do you connect to your machine after you're in VPN? RDP? VNC?